# Vue v-bind:class not working immediately when changing the binded object's value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the Vue, to add the dynamical class to the element, I think that the developers use the `v-bind:class`.
But in the below example, the `v-bind:class` doesn't work properly.

```
//Html
<div id="mainapp">
  <span class="star" v-bind:class="{gold:obj.selected}" v-on:click="clickStar()">star</span>
</div>

//Script
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#mainapp",
  data:{
    obj:{}  
  },
  methods:{
    clickStar:function(){
      if(this.obj.selected == undefined) this.obj.selected =false;
      //this.obj.selected=!this.obj.selected;
      this.$set(this.obj, 'selected', !this.obj.selected);
      console.log(this.obj);
    }
  }
})
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/trge2hu5/8/)

When clicking the element , `span` tag, the `obj.selected` value is changed by the `clickStar` function.
But v-bind:class doesn't work though `$set` is used when changing the `obj`.
[Reason that Dom is not updated](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)
What am I wrong?
How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Just sharing the link to "Reason that Dom is not updated" above helped me because I did the same thing what the link says: add a property to an object of a child component which DOM was not aware of. The moment I realized this, I removed that additional property and updated the prop in parent which re-rendered the child and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the class attributes:

```
:class="`star ${obj.selected ? 'gold' : ''}`"

methods:{
  clickStar () {
    if (this.obj.hasOwnProperty('selected') {
      this.obj.selected = !this.obj.selected
    } else {
      this.$set(this.obj, 'selected', true);
    }
  }
}
```

[Adding reactive properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Another approach would be to use a `ref`:

```
<span ref="star" class="star" @click="clickStar">star</span>

methods:{
  clickStar () {
    if (this.obj.hasOwnProperty('selected') {
      this.obj.selected = !this.obj.selected
    } else {
      this.$set(this.obj, 'selected', true);
    }

    if (this.obj.selected) {
      this.$refs.star.$el.classList.add('gold')
    } else {
      this.$refs.star.$el.classList.remove('gold')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Objects should also work, which are even better for allowing conditional classes...

Comment: Yes, and the first example would be preferred since it would be become reactive after using `this.$set`.

Comment: Is this only resolution for this issue? Without `ref` , it couldn't be solved?

Comment: No it can be solved without ref. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yours solves the issue, but why doesn't `v-bind:class`  work though using `$set`  for the `selected` of `obj`?

Comment: But https://jsfiddle.net/trge2hu5/19/ shows working with both of `class` and `v-bind:class`. I referenced your answer. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: It seems https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats is the answer of my issue mentioned in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should define all of your data properties when it initialsed.

change your data object to.

`data : {
    object: {
       selected:false

    }
 }`

fiddle updated [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trge2hu5/15/)

Comment: The property `selected` of `obj` could be added dynamically. When dynamically adding the property to object, this issue couldn't be solved?